# Android webView and google maps again

Tags: android, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile, webview

I use jquery mobile and html5 to develop my mobile application.

I have problem when I have go to other page with Google map and my position.
Directly when go to this page is everything OK (by firefox or my Android application).
When I go to my webpage by link  like " from another page nothing happen. I see only white page.
I will be really grateful for help or sugestion.

Android webView:

```
webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
             // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            // HTML5 API flags
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


            });

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                        GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
                    // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                }

                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView

               view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
}

});


            webView.loadUrl(mainUrl);
```

Html code (map.html):

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>mCB - Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
      body,html {height:100%}
      #map {width:100%;height:100%;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var marker; 
      function initGeolocation() {
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {


        var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, 
                                                          errorCallback,
                                                          {enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:Infinity,maximumAge:0});

        } else {
          console.log('Geolocation is not supported');
        }
      }

      function errorCallback() {}

      function successCallback(position) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        if(map == undefined) {
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
          addMarker(map, myLatlng, "My Position");
        }
        else 
            marker.setPosition(myLatlng);

    }

    function addMarker(map, myLatlng, title ){
        var markerOptn = {
            position:   myLatlng,
            map     :   map,
            title   :   title,

        }

        marker      =   new google.maps.Marker(markerOptn); 
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="javascript:initGeolocation()">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have found solution. It wasn't problem with webview, It was problem with ajax redirect in html code. I had to add into <a href="map.html"> data-ajax="false". Finaly my code looks like <a href="map.html" data-ajax="false">.